# Working with XML under C# - Difficulties

Tags: c#, xml

it's me again. This time, having some issues with XML. I had everything working in VB.NET (I'll show all the code I used later) but now I'm developing something else for VB application except I'm using C# for it. Part of this involves reading an XML and populating something specific into a ListBox and then being able to click on it and get the attributes for use in other controls (description loads to a text box, etc, you'll see).

I can't seem to figure out XML for the life of me in C# however. In VB, I did it like this:

```
Dim games() As String = xml...<episode>.Select(Function(n) n.Value).ToArray
AvailableEpisodes.DataSource = games
```

Where "AvailableEpisodes" is the ListBox I wish to populate. This displayed the "This is a test" term: This is a test

And then this is the SelectedIndexChanged code:

```
Dim node As XElement = xml...<episode>.First(Function(n) n.Value = AvailableEpisodes.Text)
DescriptionTextBox.Text = node.@Description
AuthorTextBox.Text = node.@Author
generatedDownloadLink = node.@DownloadLink
generatedTechName = node.@TechName
IconImage.ImageLocation = node.@IconLoc
```

What exactly would be the C# equivalent of this? I already tried copy-pasting (just figured I'd try it) and a couple code converters and none of them seem to work.

The goal of this application will be to be able to double click on the selected index and load these strings into another window (which I can work out by attaching the nodes to a string variable) I just need to get started.

Code I've tried:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(testXml))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && reader.Name == "episode")
                {
                    listBox1.DataSource = reader.GetAttribute("TechName").ToList();
                }
            }
        }
```

But that literally just outputs this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbybZ.png
Any extra information I'll toss in an edit or a reply

Thanks in advanced,

Mike

Comment: In VB.NET you are using Linq to Xml. Why not to use same approach in C#?

Answer (score 2):

Its easy: `...` corresponds to `Descendants`. `<foo>` corresponds to element name. `@bar` corresponds to attribute name.

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var node = xml.Descendants("episode")
              .First(n => n.Value == AvailableEpisodes.Text);

DescriptionTextBox.Text = (string)node.Attribute("Description");
AuthorTextBox.Text = (string)node.Attribute("Author");
generatedDownloadLink = (string)node.Attribute("DownloadLink");
generatedTechName = (string)node.Attribute("TechName");
IconImage.ImageLocation = (string)node.Attribute("IconLoc");
```

Note - if there is no matching node, then `First` will throw exception. Usually you should use `FirstOrDefault` in such case and then check node for `null`.

Comment: This seems like exactly what I need; the same method I used in VB.NET (as per suggested by someone else up above^) I'm going to play around with this a little more seeing as how I can't get the FirstOrDefault node to work.

<episodesList>
 <episode IconLoc="http://i.imgur.com/hBLOwnk.gif" TechName="testing" Description="This is just a test to make sure everything works in the XML writing and stuff." Author="Me" DownloadLink="http://google.com">This is a test</episode>
</episodesList>

That's my XML. I want the "This is a test" to be dislpayed. Tyvm though, going to play around :)

Comment: Alright this is weird now...I click the button I have set to trigger the code you suggested (minus setting the textboxes, variables, etc to the nodes, just trying to populate the listbox for now) and it does absolutely nothing. This is weird.

Answer (score 0):

Is "This is a test" supposed to be one single item in the ListBox? If it is, your logic in the C# code is wrong. Indeed, `reader.GetAttribute("TechName").ToList()` will return an array like this

```
["T","h","i", "s", " ", "i", "s", " ", "t", "e", "s", "t"]
```

Therefore, the text gets broken up into many items in the ListBox.

To read all nodes in the xml documents into ListBox, you have to create a temporary list to hold all the results read from the xml, then at the end bind the list to ListBox `listBox1.DataSource = results`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use XML Serialization?

Assuming your XML looks something like this:

```
<EpisodeData>
  <Episodes>
    <Episode Description="..." Author="..." DownloadLink="..." ... />
    <Episode Description="..." Author="..." DownloadLink="..." ... />
    <Episode Description="..." Author="..." DownloadLink="..." ... />
  </Episodes>
</EpisodeData>
```

Create classes in C# that represents the data.  Something like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class EpisodeData
{
    [XmlArray("Episodes")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Episode")]
    List<Episode> Episodes { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Episode
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string DownloadLink { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Then you can deserialize and use the data like this:

```
EpisodeData data;
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EpisodeData));
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    data = (EpisodeData)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
}

// Assuming you only want to see the description.  If you want something else
// you might want to use a DataGrid to bind to each property in Episode or 
// override ToString in Episode.
List<string> descriptions = new List<string>();
foreach (Episode episode in data.Episodes)
{
    descriptions.Add(episode.Description);
}

listBox1.DataSource = descriptions;
```

More info on XML Serialization here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx